# Passing props to ReferenceArrayField doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

When passing the pagination, perPage and sort props to reference array component they don't seem to be applied. I have a similar view but I use the ReferenceManyField passing the same props and it works there. In the docs it says you can pass these props to these components but it seems it only works with reference many. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Here are the docs I'm referencing: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html

```js
 <ReferenceArrayField
                  resource="snippets"
                  label=""
                  reference="offers"
                  target="offers"
                  basePath="/snippets"
                  source="offers"
                  record={record}
                  perPage={10}
                  pagination={<Pagination />}
                  sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' }}
                >
    <Datagrid>
       /// data grid stuff here
    </Datagrid>
</ReferenceArrayField>
```

Comment: You can pass data and not entire component .. In case you need Pagination then import it in 'ReferenceArrayField' component.

Comment: In the docs it says you can pass the pagination component if you want to add pagination controls, the 'ReferenceArrayField' is coming from the react admin package